# return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

My goal is to copy `strings_operand_table1[i]` into `label`. I would then like to return `label` to my previous function that called it. How can I fix this and what better ways are there to do this?

```
char GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
         char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int cmp_str2 = 0;
    char label[20] = {0}; 
    //int k = 0; 
    //printf(" i is %s \n", strings_label_table1[1]); 
    for(i = 0; i < 503; i++)
    {
        if(strings_mneumonic_table1[i] != NULL)`enter code here`
        {
            cmp_str2 = strcmp(strings_mneumonic_table1[i], "BASE");
            if(cmp_str2 == 0)
            {
                //printf(" ??please?? \n");
                //printf(" hex_address_table1[i] is %x \n", hex_address_table1[i]);
                strcpy(label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
                //label = strings_operand_table1[i]; 
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return label;
}
```

**Edit:**

Is this better? If I need to use pointers it seems easier to make the function void and return nothing.

```
void GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
         char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[], char *label1)
{
    int i = 0;
    int cmp_str2 = 0;
    //char label[20] = {0}; 
    //int k = 0; 
    //printf(" i is %s \n", strings_label_table1[1]); 
    for(i = 0; i < 503; i++)
    {
        if(strings_mneumonic_table1[i] != NULL)
        {
            cmp_str2 = strcmp(strings_mneumonic_table1[i], "BASE");
            if(cmp_str2 == 0)
            {
                //printf(" ??please?? \n");
                //printf(" hex_address_table1[i] is %x \n", hex_address_table1[i]);
                //strcpy(label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
                label1 = strings_operand_table1[i]; 
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    //return label;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of the function to a `char*` *AND* do not return the address of a local.

Either:

- [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) the memory for `label`:

  ```
  char* label = NULL;

  /*... snip ... */
      if(cmp_str2 == 0)
      {
          label = malloc(strlen(strings_operand_table1[i]) + 1);
          if (label)
          {
              strcpy(label, strings_operand_table1[i]);
          }
          break;
      }
  ```
- or avoid memory allocation and simply point `label` to the matching entry in `strings_operand_table1`. This is ok as the entries in `strings_operand_table1` will exist beyond the scope of the function (and it is simpler for the caller to differentiate between a failed search and failed memory allocation):

  ```
  char* label = NULL;

  /*... snip ... */
      if(cmp_str2 == 0)
      {
          label = strings_operand_table1[i]);
          break;
      }
  ```

Comment: Can you please look at my edit when you get a chance?

Comment: @cokedude, nope, that won't work. Pass in a `char** label` and `*label = ` within the function. See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html for why.

Answer (score 0):

Update function return type from `char` to `char*`

```
char GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
         char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[])
```

to

```
char* GetBaseDeclarationLabel(char *strings_label_table1[], char *strings_mneumonic_table1[],
         char *strings_operand_table1[], int hex_address_table1[])
```

**Note:**

Here you are returning pointer of local array.
See when your function returns that local array's memory will be no longer so returning that pointer is useless.

Use heap memory. Malloc for that array and return pointer of that array and after use do not forget to free it.

Comment: Can you please look at my edit when you get a chance?